# "if we will be talking in english it shall take more time."

Tags: phrase-usage

Please, help me with correct variant!

**if we will be talking in english it** (our conversation) ...

> **shall take more time.**
>
> or **takes more time.**
>
> or **is taking more time.**

I'd like to say that I prefer to talk in my language for time economy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your direct question I would say "If we will be talking in English it **will take more time**", but it sounds strange to have the verb following the "if" to be in the future tense. A native speaker would simply say "If we talk in English it will take more time".

"shall take more time" is correct, but to me at least it sounds a little less natural. This might just be because of where I live, but to me it sounds like it implies that the taking more time is something intentional rather than a natural consequence of speaking a language you are less familiar with.

"takes more time" is incorrect as "takes" is present tense.

"is taking more time" is incorrect as it is present continuous tense.

You could perhaps say "When we talk in English it takes more time" which is making a general statement of truth rather than predicting the what will happen in the future. Or, if you are already talking, you could say "Because we are talking in English it is taking more time".

Comment: I dont understand, "If we talk in English it will take more time" means the present time, as if we are already talking. In my lungauge the present cant mean the future.

Comment: That's an insightful question that I had hoped I wouldn't have to answer, because it is a bit complicated. There are even some people who argue that English doesn't have a proper future tense. I've had to do a bit of research and now I'm less sure that my original answer is completely correct.

I originally had to read your question a couple of times before I made sense of it, and now I know why: in English it is not standard to couple the simple future tense with a conditional like if. Consider this resource: https://www.ef-australia.com.au/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/